# Upper bound for the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: analysis

> Compute the limit
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+n^2}dm(x),$$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Let $f_n = \frac{x}{x^3+n^2}$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n = 0.$ I want to apply the dominated convergence theorem, to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+n^2}dm(x)=  \int_0^\infty \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x^3+n^2}dm(x) = 0,$$ but I can't find the upper bound $g \in L^1$ for $f_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\geq 1$ and $x\geq0$, we have $$f_n(x)\le \frac{x}{1+x^3}.$$ The right-hand-side is integrable over $[0,\infty[$ since $\frac{x}{1+x^3}\le \frac{\sqrt[3] 4}{3}$ and $\frac{x}{1+x^3}\le\frac1{x^2}$ for all non-negative $x$.